# Rendering HTML Content in PDF using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, render-html

I am working on a Java project where I need to generate PDFs using Apache PDFBox. The content for some of the PDF sections is provided in HTML format. I have successfully created tables, rows, and added other content using PDFBox.

However, I am facing challenges when it comes to rendering HTML content within the PDF. Currently, I'm using a combination of Apache PDFBox to PDF conversion.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import be.quodlibet.boxable.BaseTable;
import be.quodlibet.boxable.Cell;
import be.quodlibet.boxable.Row;
import be.quodlibet.boxable.Table;
import be.quodlibet.boxable.VerticalAlignment;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PdfBoxExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           // Create a new PDF document
           PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
           PDPage page = new PDPage();
           document.addPage(page);

           // Create a content stream for the PDF document
           PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

           // Set up the table parameters
           float margin = 50;
           float yStart = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - margin;
           float tableWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - 2 * margin;

           // Create a table
           Table table = new BaseTable(yStart, yStart, margin, tableWidth, margin, document, page, true, true);

           // Add a heading row
           Row headerRow = table.createRow(15);
           Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(100, "Table Heading");
           cell.setFontSize(12);
           cell.setFontBold(true);
           cell.setAlign(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);

           // Add a row with HTML content
           Feature feature = new Feature();
           // Assume feature.getText() contains HTML content
           String htmlContent = feature.getText();

           Row contentRow = table.createRow(12);
           Cell contentCell = contentRow.createCell(100, htmlContent);
           contentCell.setAlign(VerticalAlignment.TOP);

           // Draw the table
           table.draw();

           // Close the content stream
           contentStream.close();

           // Save the PDF document
           document.save("output.pdf");

           // Close the PDF document
           document.close();

           System.out.println("PDF generated successfully.");
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   // Sample Feature class with a getText() method
   static class Feature {
       public String getText() {
           // Return your HTML content here
           return "<p>This is <strong>HTML</strong> content.</p>";
       }
   }
}
```

feature.getText() -> contain below data

```
<figure class="table"> <table> <tbody> <tr> <td>Heading1</td> <td>Heading2</td> <td>Heading3</td>
</tr> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>xsxs</td> <td>xssxs</td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td>xxsxs</td>
<td>xsxsxs</td> </tr> </tbody> </table></figure>
```

The problem is that the HTML content is not rendering as expected in the PDF. I would like to display the HTML content with its formatting intact.

Has anyone successfully achieved this using Apache PDFBox? Any insights, examples, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!